# How to put XDocument elements into Comboboxes (second box dependent on first) (C# .net 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml, combobox

I'm trying to take XML and display two comboboxes. The first combobox will contain a distinct list (i.e., no duplicates) from the provinceCode elements. The second combobox will show only nameEN elements matching the provinceCode. Here is a sample of my XML:

```
<siteList>
  <site code="s0000001">
    <nameEn>Edmonton</nameEn>
    <provinceCode>AB</provinceCode>
  </site>
  <site code="s0000002">
    <nameEn>Vancouver</nameEn>
    <provinceCode>BC</provinceCode>
  </site>
...
</siteList>
```

I have my XDocument from this:

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(strSiteList);
```

I'm struggling with how to extract the unique list of provinces. It's something like:

```
var list = loaded.Descendants("provinceCode").Distinct;
```

but I'm new to C# and XDocument and I don't know what type of variable to use so I get "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable".

And I'm totally in the dark on how do to the comboboxes. I've done a quick search on stackoverflow and google, but there doesn't seem to be anything relevant on both XDocument and dependent comboboxes in C#. Is using XDocument the wrong approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually *calling* the method. You could write:

```
var list = loaded.Descendants("provinceCode").Distinct();
```

Note the brackets.

but I don't think that actually does what you want. I suspect you want:

```
List<string> list = loaded.Descendants("provinceCode")
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToList();
```

That will give you a list of distinct province codes as a list of strings.

It's not quite clear what you mean about the second list - is that meant to match just a single province code? If so:

```
List<string> names = loaded.Descendants("site")
                .Where(x => x.Element("provinceCode").Value == provinceCode) 
                .Select(x => x.Element("nameEn").Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Rookie mistake missing the brackets. Your suggestion also addressed what I actually wanted to do! And to top it off, your last bit of code also does what I need. I can build the comboboxes from here.

Comment: I have to say, I'm impressed with what XDocument/Linq can do, but I'm even more impressed by people like yourself that understand it so well and help out people like me.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Doug: LOL. LINQ to XML is a wonderful API - and LINQ in general is a wonderful technology. Have fun with them both!